# Flight Low-fare Search API - returns 500 error

Tags: amadeus

Get request for Flight Low-fare Search API (for example: https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers?origin=NYC&destination=MAD&departureDate=2019-11-11&max=2) always return 500 error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "38189",
      "title": "Internal error",
      "detail": "An internal error occurred, please contact your administrator",
      "status": "500"
    }
  ]
}
```

Something changed in API? How can I fix this?

[Flight Low-fare Search API  - returns 500 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWJCn.jpg)

Comment: Unfortunately that example request is not reproducible for us, as it requires an Authorization header. This may simply be a temporary error on their side. Have you tried to contact Amadeus support?

Comment: Yes, I've sent message to support, but unfortunately they haven't answer.

Comment: The API is down for the moment, the engineering team is working on it to fix it ASAP. Sorry for the inconvenience. I will update this when it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the API version has changed. In the test dashboard provided, some endpoints like flight offers have the version to be 2 and also some of the parameters have changed. origin is now originLocationCode and destination is destinationLocationCode. I use the Node SDK and it makes the call to version 1 and this brings up the internal server error. This doesn't provide a solution but it will be great if there is a way to specify the API version.

Comment: We released a new version of the API (Flight Offers Search) which will be the v2 of Flight Low-fare Search. You can find more information here: https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/api-release-flight-offers-search-price. Flight Low-fare Search has not been decommissioned yet as the version 2 is still in beta. The SDK will be updated when the version 2 becomes the official new version. As explained before we are facing a technical issue with Flight Low-fare Search (v1) and working on it to fix it ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Flight Low-fare Search is up and running now. Sorry for the inconvenience.